# Updating 'Now Playing' embed in Discord Music Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with the main function of playing music.
I have a *now playing* command, where it shows you how far along you are in the song, and I'd like to make this update every 5 seconds or so. I know about editing embeds, but I need it to loop consistently until the song stops. Here's the code right now:

```js
const createBar = require("string-progressbar");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "np",
  description: "Show now playing song",
  execute(message) {
    const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
    if (!queue) return message.reply(`Nothing's playing right now!`).catch(console.error);
    const song = queue.songs[0];
    const seek = (queue.connection.dispatcher.streamTime - queue.connection.dispatcher.pausedTime) / 1000;
    const left = song.duration - seek;

    let nowPlaying = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Now playing:")
      .setDescription(`${song.title}\n\`Requested by:\` ${message.author}`)
      .setColor("#ff0000")
      .setThumbnail('https://img.icons8.com/clouds/2x/play.png')
      .addField(
        "\u200b",
        new Date(seek * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8) +
          "[ " +
          createBar(song.duration == 0 ? seek : song.duration, seek, 10)[0] +
          "] " +
          (song.duration == 0 ? " ◉ LIVE" : new Date(song.duration * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)),
        false
      );

    if (song.duration > 0)
      nowPlaying.setFooter("Time Remaining: " + new Date(left * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8));

    return message.channel.send(nowPlaying);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the embed periodically with [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), and then stop editing (once the song is done) with [`clearInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp). They work like this:

```js
var countdown = 10;

// this is fine, except it doesn't stop at 0
setInterval(() => console.log(countdown--), 1000);
```

```js
// we can use `clearInterval()` to stop the interval once it gets to 0
var countdown = 10;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
 console.log(countdown--);
 if (countdown < 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for your answer - however, I'm getting an issue where it says 'Cannot edit a message sent by a different author user'. Would you know how to fix this?

It's being sent by the same user, so I don't understand why this issue is still happening.

Here's the error:
```(node:7420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user```

Comment: Huh, that's really weird. Do you have multiple clients running at the same time?

Comment: I have one client running on a server, so no - it's wierd that it's not working. I'll have a look at it and try to get it to work, but thank you for your help!